# How can I update/comment on a locked/closed question

Tags: support, comments, edits, historical-lock

There is a question which was raised almost 7 years ago which should probably be updated.

[Why would one mark local variables and method parameters as "final" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316352/why-would-one-mark-local-variables-and-method-parameters-as-final-in-java)

It should be noted that the answer is no longer accurate IMHO as the compiler has advanced in the last 7 years.  I suspect it was even inaccurate at the time, but it was so long ago it is hard to say.

Is there a process for handling answers which are locked but become in accurate over time as people still follow this advise even if the language and compilers have moved on.

Comment: In short: you can't. And based on the answers in the linked dupe, you shouldn't since the question is off topic to begin with. (that's why we don't even have "flag" option)

Comment: @ShadowWizard never the less, it has been answered and it is being cited as a reason to recommend doing this, which is no longer valid.

Comment: In these edge cases, you can bring this up in the [Tavern chat room](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) where you can usually find SO mods, and ask for them to edit or just delete the whole outdated content.